# How to force Metastock 11 to refresh chart

Tags: c#

I have done writing a C# program to write Intraday data to Metastock file. I saw some software send/post some message to Metastock to force it refresh opening charts.

How can I do this?

Comment: I guess you'll have to read the [MetaStock Developer's Kit](http://www.metastock.com/partners/developers.aspx) to find that out.

Comment: I am not using that kit, I asked Equis once to buy the SDK but they said "It not for sell". I have done my own kit. It reads and writes  data perfectly but I am stuck at forcing MS to redraw charts when new data has come. I guess I have to PostMessage to MS Windows but do not know what the messsage is.

Comment: On their site, it says: `free MetaStock Developers Kit`

Comment: That Kit have no write function, just readonly

Answer (score 0):

After digging thru the Internet, I found that the way to force MS to refresh is a little bit complicated.

1. Get the MS Main Windows (using Windows API) using its name "Metastock Professional"
2. Simulate click on menu and select Refresh data. This will refresh the actived chart only.
3. For each opened chart, set it activated and repeat step 2
4. The process will lead to annoying flickering on the screen. Some software will capture the screen, draw an image on a form that covering on top of MS window then user will not experience the flickering any more.

   But I choose a simple way: using MetaStockRefresher, a free software writing in Delphi.